# Mask with Snap.svg

Tags: mask, snap.svg

first of all here is my simple example on codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVgJwb

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="slider" src="http://i.imgur.com/iBQDddD.jpg" alt="">
    <svg id="drawing">  
    </svg>
</div>

#slider{
    position: relative;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
}
#drawing{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
}


$(document).ready(function(){

var slider_height = $("#slider").height();
var slider_width = $("#slider").width();


var s = Snap("#drawing");

var overlay = s.rect(0,0,slider_width,slider_height).attr({fill:'white',opacity:0.5});

var image = s.image('http://i.imgur.com/4fgQczZ.png', 0, 0, slider_width,slider_height);


});
```

What I want to do is to subtract the font-image from the overlay, so that the font transforms into transparent. It should be similar like -webkit-mask-image. Is it possible to do that with snap.svg or should I take another framework? I also tested svg.js but I have no clue how to do that.
Anyone can help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean something like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOaGOv ? Not quite sure what you are after that isn't opacity...but I've included example as a mask to give ideas.

Comment: No, the white opacity layer should stay. The font should cut through the layer, so that just the shape of the font is visible and you see the background image through the font

Comment: Like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpjbzB (needs a black image though if thats possible)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Didnt know that I need a black image. Thank you very much!